# Can I get word to ignore the macro security setting for one specific file?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, macros

The Word security seems to be.

1. You can't run any macros at all so there.
2. You can run some but I'll keep asking you are you sure are you sure are you sure until you choose option 3.
3. You can run anything including Virus macros but we warned you so now you're on your own.

Is it possible to let word know that Macros can be run on certain files only, or from a certain directory.

I know this is probably possible with code signing but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using the trusted locations option in the Word trust center, you can specify a location where any file put in there will be trusted and macros will be able to be run.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you trust yourself you could just turn off this warning for all files.

[image]